# SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry - configurable products

Tags: sql, magento-1.9

In our shop the customer sometimes receives the following error when placing an order:

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry
>   '11916-0-1' for key 'PRIMARY', query was: INSERT INTO
>   `mg_configurablegridview_product_index_price_final_tmp` SELECT
>   `e`.`entity_id`, `cg`.`customer_group_id`, `cw`.`website_id` (the
>   error continues after this and ends like this) WHERE (e.type_id =
>   'simple') AND (ta_status.value=1) AND (e.entity_id IN('11914',
>   '11915', '11916', '11976', '11977', '11978', '12059', '12061',
>   '12163', '12164', '12246', '12247', '12248', '12528', '12529',
>   '12530', '12531', '15854', '15855', '15857', '15856', '16679',
>   '20219', '20220', '20221', '20222', '20224', '18106', '18109',
>   '18111', '18115', '18117', '18119', '20201', '20202', '20203',
>   '20204', '20205', '20212', '20201', '20202', '20203', '20204',
>   '20205', '20212')) .

I have a hunch that it is when someone tries to buy the product with the ID/SKU called 11916 (dog collar). But I could be barking up the wrong tree. This product is part of a configurable product with various colors and sizes. No other products has this number as either ID/SKU or item number or name. But I noticed that we have the same simple products in several configurable products. For example the black collars have its own configurable product but is also in the configurable product with ALL the dog collars. Could this be causing the error?
I hope someone can help explain or maybe even come up with a solution to this SQL error.

We are using Magento version 1.9.2.3.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could it be if a customer tries to add the same product twice in an order? In that case the product shouldn't be added one more time, instead the count should be updated for the already existing row.

Comment: This is the primary key constraint issue on one of the column of this table mg_configurablegridview_product_index_price_final_tmp , please try to check the schema of the table and see there might be an primary key column in which you  are trying to insert duplicate data, hope will be helped.

Comment: @Charanjeet Singh - where do I find the mg_configurablegridview_product_index_price_final_tmp ? I am very new at Magento and know nothing about SQL errors.